# Should windows smart screen block also files on the hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-smartscreen

I've downloaded a .zip file containing a .exe program which was created with visual studio.

So far so fine. I didn't use IE but instead chrome and it all worked.

On my hard drive I unzipped the file and tried to run it and.....

[image]

In essence the translation is: Windows SmartScreen blocked the execution of the program.

As I always thought that smartscreen only was checking for downloads via IE and not execution of programs already on the hard drive, I'm wondering here what is up there. Is that normal behaviour of smart screen?

(I've started signed and unsigned .exe files before and never had it pop up so it is confusing me a lot there).

Comment: If you `Right Click` the `exe` and click `Properties`, do you have a button to `Unblock` it at the bottom?

Comment: yepp have that one (took me a while as the german edition of the properties names it.....lets say it so not a 100% word by word translation there)

Comment: @jonno is that the reason for that? (if so why only for that one file and not others?

Comment: Windows SmartScreen is feature in Windows 8 and above.  It expands the underline feature introduced in IE9 to the OS itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blocking is caused by an NTFS stream associated with the file, based on the source the file came from (Trusted, Internet, Intranet, or Untrusted).

You can unblock the file by `Right Click`ing it, going to `Properties`, and clicking `Unblock`. This removes the tag against the file.

You are right in that this behaviour is usually associated with Internet Explorer. I can't say for certain, but as you downloaded it from Chrome, it would seem that Chrome also tags these files if it believe they come from an unsafe source. However, any file that contains this stream will throw the check, not just when trying to run it IE, but it's stored against the file (and any extracted files from it in the case of ZIP files and the like.)

Further reading can be found [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-the-internet-file-blocking-and-unblocking).

Comment: So its nothing about the file itself but that it is not from a known source/explicitely trusted source AND in addition to this form the internet. And that causes this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, unless it's a known trusted source, it will be tagged as untrusted until you unblock it. The contents of the file itself could be, and usual are, perfectly fine.

Comment: Tnx. Was the first time that thing acted up so got a bit unsure there as I never had it acting up before^^